# CC_PROCESSOR_NOT_FOUND error while creating customer deposit record in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Error is as below when tried to create customer deposit record using sales **order id**.

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"CC_PROCESSOR_NOT_FOUND","message":"A suitable credit card processing profile was not found for this transaction.","stack":["<anonymous>(N/record/recordService.js)","<anonymous>(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:36)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"CC_PROCESSOR_NOT_FOUND","details":"A suitable credit card processing profile was not found for this transaction.","userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["<anonymous>(N/record/recordService.js)","<anonymous>(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:36)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}
```

What is the value to be set to the `fieldId 'creditcardprocessor'` to avoid this error.Explained with an example is a great help.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't supply a valid **creditcardprocessingprofile** record id to that field.

This is what this fields means:

```
Select the credit card processor you want to use for this transaction.
You can set up credit card processors at > > Set Up Credit Card Processing.
```

You are missing a payment provider like CyberSource. This is a user-provided option not a list of pre-set options. Ask your accounting dept to set one up